# Cannot access to my Vuejs methods and attributes in EJS file

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuejs2, ejs

```
<form id="signup-form">
    <h1 style="text-align: center;">SIGNUP</h1>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" v-model="password">
    </div>
    <input v-on:click="signup()" type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg" value="Signup" />
</form>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script>
    const vue = new Vue({
        data: {
            email: '',
            password:''
        },
        methods: {
            signup: function () {
                console.log('email is: ' + this.email)
            }
        }
    })
</script>
```

Nothing happened when I clicked on Signup button, and email/password in data don't change. How could I fix this?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you try to add ```el: "#signup-form"``` at the same level as data and methods ?

Comment: Yeah, when running Vue through a CDN you gotta make sure to specify the main parent element that Vue should bind to, otherwise nothing is going to happen.

Comment: @marsnebulasoup Got it now thanks! Is there any better way to use Vuejs inside EJS files in NodeJS projects?

Comment: @Amine.B  Unfortunately, I don't have enough experience with EJS to answer that question, but after some research, it seems like what you're doing right now is probably the easiest way. It may be possible to integrate EJS with `vue-cli` somehow, but it seems to me that that'd take a good deal or work to set up. I found [a plugin](https://github.com/anncwb/vite-plugin-html) for [`vite`](https://vitejs.dev) which can apparently inject EJS into the `index.html` file of a Vite Vue app, but that seems to be for adding additional functionality unrelated to Vue, so I don't think it'd be of much help.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you found a solution already. But for someone looking for that solution, here it is.

It is quiet simple actually, you forgot to define where the Vue logic/app should be mounted, like so:

```
<script>
    const vue = new Vue({

        // add this:
        el: '#signup-form',
        // that's all


        data: {
            email: '',
            password:''
        },
        methods: {
            signup: function () {
                console.log('email is: ' + this.email)
            }
        }
    })
</script>
```

Maybe you can let us know if that works for you.
Happy coding